# Small fast pseudorandom number generator in C++

Tags: c++, random, c++17

I've been away from C++ for some time and I'd like to get back up to speed with modern practices, so I implemented a small random number generator described [here](https://burtleburtle.net/bob/rand/smallprng.html).

Any advice on this piece of code?

```
    #include <cstdint>
    #include <cstddef>
    #include <limits>
    #include <random>

// implementation of Bob Jenkins' small prng https://burtleburtle.net/bob/rand/smallprng.html
namespace Random {
    namespace detail { 
        using _rand32_underlying = uint32_t;
        using _rand64_underlying = uint64_t;

        template<size_t N> struct rand_type { using type = void; };
        template<> struct rand_type<32> { using type = _rand32_underlying; };
        template<> struct rand_type<64> { using type = _rand64_underlying; };

    }

    // public
    template <size_t N> 
    using rand_t = typename detail::rand_type<N>::type;
    using rand32_t = rand_t<32>;
    using rand64_t = rand_t<64>;

    template <size_t N>
    inline rand_t<N> rot(rand_t<N> x, rand_t<N> k) noexcept { return ((x << k) | (x >> (N - k))); }

    template<size_t N>
    class SmallPrng
    {
        public:
            using result_type = rand_t<N>;
            inline rand_t<N> min() { return std::numeric_limits<result_type>::min(); }
            inline rand_t<N> max() { return std::numeric_limits<result_type>::max(); }

            rand_t<N> a, b, c, d;

            inline rand32_t prng32() 
            {
                rand32_t e = a - rot<N>(b, 27);
                a = b ^ rot<N>(c, 17);
                b = c + d;
                c = d + e;
                d = e + a;
                return d;        
            }

            inline rand64_t prng64()
            {
                rand64_t e = a - rot<N>(b, 7); 
                a = b ^ rot<N>(c, 13);
                b = c + rot<N>(d, 37);
                c = d + e;
                d = e + a;
                return d;
            }

        public:
            explicit SmallPrng(result_type seed = 0xdeadbeef) noexcept
            {
                static_assert(!(N != 32 && N != 64), "You can only construct a small prng in 32 or 64 bit mode.");
                a = 0xf1ea5eed;
                b = c = d = seed;
                for(size_t i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
                    (*this)();
            }

            explicit SmallPrng(std::random_device &rd) : SmallPrng(rd()) {}

            inline rand_t<N> operator()() noexcept
            {
                if constexpr(N == 32) 
                    return prng32();
                return prng64();
            }
    };
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `a, b, c, d` be private?

Comment: Are you familiar with DeMorgan's Law? An expression like `!(N != 32 && N != 64)` is a bit silly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The `SmallPrng(std::random_device &rd)` constructor seems like an utility method. It spares the client a single call to `seed = rd()`, but forces an inclusion of (otherwise unnecessary) `<random>`. IMHO, this constructor is absolutely unnecessary.
- The purpose of the

  ```
          for(size_t i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
              (*this)();
  ```

  loop in the constructor is seems useless; it amounts to passing a different seed. In any case, use `{}` around the loop body.
- An asymmetry between

  ```
          b = c + d;
  ```

  in `prng32()` and

  ```
          b = c + rot<N>(d, 37);
  ```

  in `prng64()` is striking. Needs a comment, at least.
- As mentioned in comments, the `static_assert(!(N != 32 && N != 64), ....)` is equivalent to `static_assert((N == 32 || N == 64), ....)` which is IMHO much cleaner.

Comment: Thanks, I accepted your answer. However I think the loop in the constructor is not useless, it correctly initializes the whole state (a, b, c, d).